# Corresponding plugins not removed while unistalling a feature in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

1) First i installed a feature from eclipse update site via eclipse -> **Help > Install New Software**

2) I unistall the same from eclipse ->  **Help > About Eclipse**

3) in /features  uninstalled feature was removed . But the corresponding plugins are exist in /plugins .

why , how can i remove them while unistalling a feature ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which eclipse version are you using?

This was an expected behavior in eclipse 3.4. When the system is running the plug-ins won't be removed because they could be running or they could be necessary to close. Plug-ins are removed the next time an install or an uninstallation is performed implicitly or explicitly. Following would be the sequence:

```
- Install A
- Install B
- Uninstall A
- Uninstall B -> Now A is garbage collected
- Uninstall C -> Now B is garbage collected
```

Have a look at [Bug 232356](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=232356) which talks about this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Check the plaform.xml under \eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.update
The feature should have been removed. if it is not, then there were some issues while uninstalling.

Comment: Hi , I verified in platform.xml . That feature was removed from platform.xml not in plugins directory .